# Change href link in content place holder from C# code

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a content placeholder containing a link:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content5" runat="server"  contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder3">
<a href= "../WOPages/WO_Main.aspx?WONum=12345">WorkOrder</a>
```

and I would like to change the href querystring from code.  How do I find it to change it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If you add an `id` and a `runat="server"` attribute to your link...

```
<a id="YourLink" runat="server" href="../WOPages/WO_Main.aspx?WONum=12345">
    WorkOrder
</a>
```

...then you can access/change the [`HRef`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.href.aspx) property programmatically...

```
YourLink.HRef = "http://stackoverflow.com/";
```

Comment: I'm missing something basic here (I'm a newbie) I tried this code and am getting an error 'The name YourLink does not exist in the current context'  on the YourLink part of the YourLink.HRef statement.

Comment: I just figured this out:  in the Page parameters of the .aspx file, the 'Codefile' parameter was pointing to the file name: 'LabEdit.aspx.cs'.  It should have been pointing to the path: "~/WOPages/LabEdit.aspx.cs".  I know I didn't move the code file or the page file, so this is maybe a problem with VS2008.

Answer (score 2):

You could clear all controls from the ContentPlaceholder and then add a new hyperlink control like this:

```
// Create your hyperlink control
HyperLink lnk = new HyperLink();
lnk.NavigateUrl = "http://domain.com";
lnk.Text = "Click here";

ContentPlaceHolder3.Controls.Clear();
ContentPlaceHolder3.Controls.Add(lnk);
```

or give the hyperlink an Id and update the hyperlink by finding the control in the ContentPlaceholder:

```
HyperLink lnk = ContentPlaceHolder3.FindControl("MyLink") as HyperLink;
lnk.NavigateUrl = "http://domain.com/update/";
lnk.Text = "Click here too";
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use render tags or do this:

```
<a href="<asp:literal id="hrefString" runat="server"></asp:literal>"
```

and assign the literal in code.

Answer (score 0):

As the link is not a server control, the place holder contains a LiteralControl where the text is the HTML code. You can get the HTML code and replace the href attribute:

```
LiteralControl c = Content5.Controls[0] as LiteralControl;
c.Text = Regex.Replace(c.Text, "(href=\")[^\"]+(\")", "$1http://www.guffa.com$2");
```

If you add `runat="server"` and an id to the link so that it's a server control, it gets a lot simpler, as you can just set it's `HRef` property.